# WebStorm treat TypeScript files as JavaScript

Tags: webstorm

I my ES6 project most of my files have a normal `.js` extension while some others have `.ts` (for code sharing reasons).

WebStorm's code inspections cannot see the imports for the JavaScript packages.

I would like WebStorm to treat the `.ts` as if they were `.js` files.

Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | File Types**, add `<your_file_name>.ts` to **JavaScript** file type patterns